# MySQL: Create View with Concatenation - syntax error

Tags: mysql, view, concatenation

I am building a small database and am trying to create a view that will show the customer's first and last name together and am getting a syntax error for the `FROM CUSTOMER` at the end of the code. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CUST_ID      INT    NOT NULL     AUTO_INCREMENT     UNIQUE,
CUST_LNAME      VARCHAR(25)    NOT NULL,
CUST_FNAME      VARCHAR(25)    NOT NULL,
CUST_STREET_NO   VARCHAR(6),
CUST_STREET_NAME     VARCHAR(25),
CUST_APT_NO     VARCHAR(10),
CUST_CITY     VARCHAR(25),
CUST_STATE     CHAR(2),
CUST_ZIP_CODE     CHAR(5),
PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE VIEW V_Customer AS
SELECT   
CUST_ID,   
CONCAT(CUST_FNAME ," ",CUST_LNAME ) FULL_NAME,
CUST_STREET_NO,
CUST_STREET_NAME,
CUST_APT_NO,
CUST_CITY,
CUST_STATE,
CUST_ZIP_CODE,
FROM CUSTOMER;
```

Comment: ... `CUST_ZIP_CODE FROM CUSTOMER;` remove the last `,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the comma after CUST_ZIP_CODE. You have a FROM clause right after it, so it's the last field you are pulling, which means you don't need a comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW V_Customer AS
SELECT   
CUST_ID,   
CONCAT(RTRIM(CUST_FNAME) ,' ',CUST_LNAME ) FULL_NAME, -- remove spaces
CUST_STREET_NO,
CUST_STREET_NAME,
CUST_APT_NO,
CUST_CITY,
CUST_STATE,
CUST_ZIP_CODE  -- , Remove this comma as this is the last field in the list
FROM CUSTOMER;

-- In SQL Server we use single quotes for text, (I only have SQL Server), 
-- so if double quotes works for mySQL, then change the blank text above 
-- to double quotes
```

Comment: MySQL uses the single quotes, but in any case, you were right about my needing to remove the comma after ZIP_CODE. Thanks for your help!